# How to extract public profile information from Facebook based on name using curl utility

Tags: api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-authorization

I am trying to extract all public profile information i.e. name,birthday,location,gender, hometown,education, hobby using curl utility. I am using proper access token but I am only able to extract id,name,gender based on any name search using curl utility.

Can anybody help me on what exact steps to follow to extract all public information shared by a person in Facebook using curl utility.

An early reply is highly appreciated.

Comment: I'd start here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/ - to understand the auth model Facebook uses

Answer (score 1):

Set the URL first:

```
$url = https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/?fields=name,email,username,birthday
```

Now, call this function curlify

```
$contents = curlify($url);
```

This is the function:

```
function curlify($url)
{
    $c = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $contents = curl_exec($c);
    $err  = curl_getinfo($c,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($c);

    return $contents;
}
```

It will return the data in JSON format